# Firebase Realtime database with flutter ERROR

Tags: firebase-realtime-database, flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have started learning flutter. And was trying to integrate the firebase realtime database into my flutter project. But as soon as I added the dependencies to my build.graddle files of the android part I started to get this error.

```
Launching lib\main.dart on A37f in debug mode...
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\Username 
\Desktop\firebase_listview\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file 'C:\Users\Username\Desktop\firebase_listview\android\app\build.gradle' line: 24

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> ASCII

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get 
more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 3s
Command: C:\Users\Username\Desktop\firebase_listview\android\gradlew.bat app:properties
```

It started when I added

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

to the bottom of the app level build.graddle

And This

```
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2'
```

to my project level gradle file.

I have also added firebase_databasse dependency in the pubspec.yaml file for the flutter under dependencies

Answer (score 0):

Try to change google services classpath
from
classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.2`
to
classpath `com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0`